# What is this 'white waveform' called and what's it's function in Pro Tools HD 9

Tags: pro-tools, avid

I want to know what the white waveform means (it's underlined using red colour in the pic attacthed). Can you tell me what it is called and which function it has?

[image: check this pic]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is only activated when the cursor is over a track that is displaying a waveform, and next to it, the sample value for that position of the mouse over the track.

For example, if you are working on some volume automation for a certain track, try hovering the mouse over that particular track to see how that white waveform icon disappears from the transport area.